# New Record Highlight or Bold In Asp.Net ,HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, repeater

how to highlight or bold new record  i try below html ,sp

repeater code

```
<table class="CSSTableGenerator" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="results">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" OnItemCommand="Repeater2_ItemCommand" runat="server"
        OnItemDataBound="Repeater2_ItemDataBound">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <tr>
                <%-- <td>
                                   DocumentID
                                </td>--%>
                <td>
                    Document Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    File Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    Uploaded By
                </td>
                <td>
                    Uploaded Date
                </td>
                <td>
                    Email
                </td>
                <td>
                    Department
                </td>
                <td>
                    Status
                </td>
            </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="DocId" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocID")%>' />
                <%--<asp:Label Id="DocId" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocID")%>'></asp:Label>--%>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="DocName" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocumentName")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Uploadfile" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Uploadfile")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UploadedBy")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="UploadedDate" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UploadedDate")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="YourEamil" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserEmail")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="DepType" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Department")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ApproveID") %>' Visible="false" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfDepartmentId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ApproveID") %>' />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" class="vpb_dropdown1"
                        DataTextField="ApproveType" DataValueField="ApproveID" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Pending" Selected="selected" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Approve" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Reject" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

this is the sp when user upload document

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[fileupload]
@DocDesciption nvarchar(50),
@DocName nvarchar(50),
@Uploadfile nvarchar(50),
@DocTypeID int,
@DepID int,

@UploadedBy nvarchar(50),
@UserID int
as
insert into DocumentInfo(DocDesciption,DocName,UploadedDate,Uploadfile,DocTypeID,DepID,UploadedBy,ApproveID,UserID,Viewed )
values(@DocDesciption,@DocName,GETDATE(),@Uploadfile,@DocTypeID,@DepID,@UploadedBy,3,@UserID,'false')
```

when i upload new document and in table it shows me like this please check this pic table
[table](http://oi59.tinypic.com/b3wl7a.jpg)

and in .aspx i set like this

```
<tr class="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Viewed") == "false" ? "highlight" : string.Empty %>">
```

there is .aspx upload document form and another view document form in .aspx uplaod document form user upload document in this form and his/her document view in .aspx view-document form

for view document i use this sp

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[UserIDDoc]

@UserID int
as
Select DISTINCT dbo.DocumentInfo.Viewed, dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID as DocumentID,
dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName,
dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedDate as UploadedDate, dbo.DocType.DocType as Document,

dbo.Department.DepType as Department, dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded,

dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType AS Status

FROM dbo.DocumentInfo inner JOIN dbo.DocType ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID=dbo.DocType.DocTypeID
inner JOIN dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID=dbo.Department.DepID

inner join dbo.ApproveType on dbo.DocumentInfo.ApproveID=dbo.ApproveType.ApproveID
left JOIN dbo.Approval ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID = dbo.Approval.DocID
where UserID=@UserID
```

but when i view document then documents not in bold or highlight check this pic

[repeater pic](http://oi58.tinypic.com/2vrwo7b.jpg)

Comment: i want to bold whole row

Comment: Then share your repeater code here...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Add the style in your table, `style="font-weight:bold"`. e.g,

```
<table class="CSSTableGenerator" border="0" style="font-weight:bold" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="results" >
```

or you can also define `font-weight:bold` style into your `CSSTableGenerator` it will works the same for you.

For highlighting, you can do that in RowDataBound event of the datagrid.

For e,g.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    int noOfRows = ((DataTable)GridView1.DataSource).Rows.Count;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    { 
        if(e.Row.RowIndex == noOfRows -1 )
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok then when user click on row then i want in normal postion means not in bold and when user add record in repeater then i want to bold this new record and when click on row then it becomes in normal position.....same as we see in gmail emails when any new email comes it beacomes bold and when we click on email it becomes normal postion means not in bold

Comment: It means you want to highlight the new record and when user clicks/views it, it becomes normal like existing records.

Comment: i use repeater not gridview... so how i change this line if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)